# Searching through facebook posts based on keywords Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I go find a user's posts and comments based on a certain keyword?

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no API for that.

What you can still search for via API, is pretty limited these days. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/#searchtypes

Comment: And how do they manage the social listening solutions announcing that in their functionality list? I mean: What do really offer?

Comment: @AlexAcc I don't understand what you are trying to ask there, not at all.

Comment: I mean: How do they manage for trends analysis, to search content by keywords, over Facebook?

Comment: @AlexAcc some companies who offer such services might scrape the data, or accumulate it based on the mass of users that have given them access to _their_ specific FB data, or they might have specific agreements in place with Facebook, for extended access to that kind of data. Really not a question that can be universally answered.

Comment: I know that is very abstract question, but I'm curious about how to "search content by keywords" in Facebook. Pretty easy in Twitter, even in Instagram by #hashtags, but seems impossible in Facebook using the API...

Comment: Yes, it _is_ impossible. At least for normal 3rd-party apps. Facebook partners might have access to special, non-public APIs.

Comment: And is it possible to search in all groups?

Comment: No, not possible either. Only access to a specific group’s feed is possible, but it requires the app to be “installed” in the group, and even then there’s no search either, you could only go through the posts yourself.